# Be behind someone, be ahead of someone

Tags: word-usage, phrases

Are the phrases I used in the sentences below used in English?  Are they natural  and common  in colloquial language?..

Like someone falls behind someone, can these sentences be used:

> I'm **behind** everyone my age.
>
> I'm **behind** my class.

And similarly can "ahead of someone " be used to mean that someone  is "better thank someone ".

> I'm **ahead of** a lot of kids my age.
>
> I'm **ahead of** everyone in my class.

So these sound natural and is it common and used ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, those are natural. Without anything in context to make it more specific, one would generally take it to mean that they had made less/more progress in their studies - either for the "age" case if it was a kid, or the "my class" case whatever the age.